# Show all compile errors in FlexBuilder?

Tags: apache-flex, compiler-construction, intellij-idea, flexbuilder

Is it possible to make FlexBuilder show all compile errors in all files? FlexBuilder does not show errors in Action Script files, that are not referenced. Also very often I fix a problem just to see new problems pop up after compiling the whole project although these errors existed long before.

IntelliJ is showing all compile errors it can find and I would like to have FlexBuilder behaving the same way since IntelliJ is not mature enough to handle our complex set up. Is there a compiler switch to enable this?

Comment: How does IntelliJ do Flex builds? Does it use mxmlc?

Comment: Yes... Basically it creates a config report XML file that is passed to the mxmlc compiler with all options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler can (and will) show errors only in code that you tell it to compile, and like you said, whatever is not referenced in the code you compile, will not be compiled, and thus, checked by the compiler.

So if you want to have the compiler check some part of your code, you need to tell it to compile it. I'm not sure how your projects are set up, but I'm assuming that you're compiling a bunch of smaller projects that are all using different parts of a shared codebase (or something similar.) In this case, you could either:

- set up some sort of "master" project that references all of your code, compiling which would then check for errors everywhere (maybe you have this already, in which case the solution is simply to compile this regularly)
- set up a job/target for compiling the AsDoc documentation for all of your code -- you could then run this regularly and at the same time you'd be keeping your API docs up to date

Answer (score 0):

The following MXMLC compiler arguments might be useful:

**-includes *className* [...]**

Links one or more classes into the output SWF, regardless of whether they are required at compile time.

**-include-libraries *swcPath* [...]**

Links the entire contents of one or more SWC libraries into the output SWF, regardless of whether its classes are required at compile time.